Lorentz transformation from the Minkowski metric
Is it possible to derive the matrix:
$$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & -\beta\gamma \\
-\beta\gamma & \gamma 
\end{pmatrix}$$
From the condition:
$$\Lambda g\Lambda^T=g \ \ \ \ g=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
 0  & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
I couldn't find this way of deriving the Lorentz transformations online and also couldn't think of a way to derive them myself. I want to see them derived that way because this condition is deeply connected with preserving the canonical form of the wave equations arising from the Lorentz gauge of the electromagnetic potentials. Here is my shot:
We assume:
$$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
 c  & d 
\end{pmatrix} \\ \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
 c  & d 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
 0  & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a & c \\
 b  & d 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
 c  & d 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
-a & -c \\
 b  & d 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-a^2+b^2 & -ac+bd \\
 -ac+bd  & -c^2+d^2 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
 0  & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \\ \Rightarrow \begin{cases} a^2-b^2=1 \\ d^2-c^2=1 \\ ac-bd=0  \end{cases}$$
Where do I go from here?

You could try with an ansatz for $\Lambda  = (a b, c d)$ and see if you can solve for $a,b,c,d$.

I already tried that and it didn't lead me anywhere

Could you edit the answer with your attempt to see where it goes wrong?

I'm not sure what matrix you want to derive here, as in what it means. You mean assuming $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$ where $|\beta|<1$? You need a bit more conditions on what matrix it is you want to derive

"Where do I go from here?" You have three equations and four unknowns, so start eliminating some of the unknowns...

Let $$\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\Lambda g \Lambda^T = g$$
By taking the determinant of both sides we conclude
$$\det{\Lambda}\det{\Lambda^T} =1 $$
$$\det{\Lambda} = \pm 1$$
We expect that the identity matrix is one valid form of a Lorentz transformation, and so $\det{\Lambda}=1.$
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
We also assume that the Lorentz transform is invertible:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} d & -c \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix} $$
So
$$\begin{pmatrix} -a & b \\ -c & d \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} -d & c \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$
Implying $a=  d,$ $b= c.$
Now the matrix looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix} \gamma & b \\ b & \gamma \end{pmatrix}$$
together with the determinant condition $a^2 - b^2 =1$ lets us rewrite $b=\pm\sinh w=\gamma\beta,\,a=\cosh w=\gamma$ in terms of rapidity.
So we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} \gamma & \pm \gamma \beta \\ \pm \gamma \beta & \gamma \end{pmatrix}$$
The factor of $\pm$ here reflects the fact that both $\beta$ and $-\beta$ are valid, they are just velocities in different directions.

What extra physical conditions would I need to derive the expression for $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$?

If you add the condition that it maps a state with velocity zero to a state with velocity $v$, you should get the right value for $\beta$. I did this in a class a long time ago.

A minor technicality, but you need both proper (det = 1) and orthochronous conditions to get the restricted Lorentz group which are the transformations normally considered.

"We also assume that the Lorentz transform is invertible..." You just showed that the determinant is non-zero ($\det \Lambda = \pm 1$), so you do not have to assume it is invertible, you have already shown it to be invertible.

@hft Yeah, I realized that right after, lol

You can edit your answer.


Is it possible to derive the matrix:
$$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & -\beta\gamma \\
-\beta\gamma & \gamma 
\end{pmatrix}$$
From the condition:
$$\Lambda g\Lambda^T=g \ \ \ \ g=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
 0  & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

No. It is not possible to derive the matrix $\Lambda$ from the above condition alone.
Depending on a choice of sign, you will either end up with:
$$
\Lambda = \left(\begin{matrix}\gamma & -\beta\gamma \\ -\beta\gamma & \gamma\end{matrix}\right)
$$
or
$$
\Lambda = \left(\begin{matrix}\gamma & -\beta\gamma \\ +\beta\gamma & -\gamma\end{matrix}\right)\;.
$$
If you also demand the condition
$$
\det(\Lambda)=1
$$
then you can derive the form of $\Lambda$ that you seek, but note that at this point $\gamma$ is still an arbitrary real number, not necessarily greater than 1 (you need to impose further conditions on $\gamma$ to make physical sense).

Update:
As mentioned in the comments, an orthochronous condition should be imposed since, usually, we take $\gamma$ to mean:
$$
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} \ge 1
$$
Regarding the condition that
$$
\det(\Lambda) = 1\;,
$$
the transformations with $\det(\Lambda)=1$ are called "proper," by definition. These includes boosts and rotations. The "improper" transformations include parity and time reversal.

What would be the physical meaning of imposing such a condition? Is the second $\Lambda$ you wrote an invalid Lorentz transformation? If yes, why?

@hft You need both proper (det = 1) and orthochronous conditions in order to arrive at the restricted Lorentz group which are the transformations usually considered.

@VincentThacker Are improper transformations also valid? I'm struggling with understanding the physical meaning of this condition. Why would it be wrong to flip the x axis?

@KrumKutsarov No, they are not always physically valid, see the end of this answer. Clearly, without the orthochronous requirement, time reversal is possible which is not always physically valid.

@VincentThacker I updated my answer to address your comment.

As I mentioned in one of the comments. You can solve for the fact that $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$ if you add the condition that,
$$ \Lambda \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ v\end{bmatrix} $$
For simplicity, I am working in units where $c = 1$. This simply says that a boost does what we expect, it maps a four-velocity with three-velocity zero to a four-velocity with three-velocity $v$.

Here's a quick way to see that you can't do it, choose $\Lambda = g$. Then, $\Lambda^T=\Lambda=g$ and you can check that:
$$ \Lambda g \Lambda^T = g g g = g $$
But $g$ is definitely not a Lorentz transformation.

Ok so I need the condition that $det(\Lambda)=1$. What is the physical meaning of such condition?

@KrumKutsarov See for example discussion here, among other things, it ensures that the spacetime interval is invariant.
